# MAAS 1.9.1 GUI Link interface

Tags: juju, maas, openstack-autopilot

I have two interfaces on MAAS 1.9.1
eth0 - External Network
eth1 - Private/Internal Network ie 10.x.x.x with DHCP/DNS configured

I have MAAS GUI configured to access over eth0
ie http://192.168.1.45/MAAS

wondering if i need to point MAAS GUI over the internal/private Network
If so what would be the command to make the link change with new internal IP

Answer (score 2):

By default MAAS GUI (well, Apache actually) is listening on all available interfaces (take a look at */etc/apache2/conf-enabled/maas-http.conf*), so unless you have tweaked your Apache configuration otherwise in /etc/apache2/ports.conf, GUI will be accessible from your private network too.

I guess that you do not actually mean GUI – you mean access of your MAAS server from internal network where your deployed machines are via HTTP. Access to DHCP and TFTP ports is needed, lot's of packets are transmitted to ports 3260, 5240, 5248, 8000, but port 80? No, not needed if you have everything (controllers) in one server. Even tried running tcpdump on MAAS server for curiosity.

Comment: Great....and that is indeed the correct assumption....Thank you for your reply......